# Managing multiple activities in android application

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android application with many activities. I render next activity from the previous by creating an Intent object right in its code. I think this kind of code sucks. Are there any "good" ways to implement activities management in the application, best practices?

Comment: Did you check the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)?

Comment: Dan, ActivityManager doesn't allow to create connections between activities, create sequences, avoid making Intents within other activities.

Comment: Sorry, [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)

Comment: Do you say : "I think this kind of code sucks"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are some standard practices that we android developer follows:

1. Create DashBoard and start activities based on the particular dashboard option click
2. Follow Tab-bar design

**About Dashboard:**

[image]

You can get the example for Dashboard from [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/build-dashboard-ui-for-android/).

**About TabBar:**
Why i prefer Dashboard as compared to Tabbar? Just because it is really very much easy to implement activity management in dashboard while in tab layout we have to implement [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) concept and really very much hard to handle as compared to Dashboard layout.

Comment: i have download the dashboard sample and imported to eclipse and i get bunch of errors when i try to run.

`
Description Resource Path Location Type
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. DashboardDemo  line 1 Android ADT Problem
Project 'DashboardDemo' is missing required source folder: 'gen' DashboardDemo  Build path Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved DashboardDemo  Unknown Java Problem
`

Comment: 1. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. 2. Project -> Clean

Comment: Even you can have my article/example for [**Dashboard design pattern implementation**](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-dashboard-design-pattern-implementation/)

Answer (score 0):

Activities in Android are designed to be very decoupled from each other.  This is partially apparent by the idea of launching an activity with an 'intent'.  It doesn't even sound specific.

If you're uncomfortable with this paradigm you can look into using `Fragments` or `ActivityGroups`.  And though I wouldn't normally recommend this, you could write your own Activity Manager that wraps the Intents and makes launching and managing activities a little more explicit.

Comment: what do you think about creating static method which returns an singleton Intent object in every activity?

Comment: @Sergey My personal thoughts are that it's best to adopt the paradigms of the language or platform that you're using.  And that static methods and singletons are not usually good OO designs.  But I don't know the code.  You might have a good reason for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I had an app that had 4 views that I wanted to be able to cycle through:

> [Back to C]<->D<->A<->B<->C<->[Next to D]

I should point out that each of the 4 activities had a common title bar control that had next/prev buttons on it.

I made a class called ActivityOrderer that had a static list of Class and two functions, next and prev.  For example, next did this:

```
public static Class<?> nextActivityClass(Class<?> current) {
    int currentIndex = _orderedActivities.indexOf(current);
    int nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % _orderedActivities.size();
    return _orderedActivities.get(nextIndex);
}
```

Now, each Activity I created would just call set the TitleBar's next and prev buttons to start the Intent created like:

```
_titleBar.setNextIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityOrderer.nextActivityClass(getClass())));
```